# Getting Bitmap from Video decoded with Nestream AppendBytes (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, video-processing, netstream

I am wondering if someone who has handled `NetStream.appendBytes` in **Flash** knows how to get the `bitmapData` from a decoded video frame? I have already looked at  **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607047/how-can-i-use-bitmapdata-draw-with-netstream-appendbytes)** but that is from 3 years ago and the more recent comment/answer seems to be gone. **In 2014** has anyone managed to turn those bytes into a bitmap? I am working with Flash Player 11.8 and this is not a desktop/AIR app.

In the image below I can do steps **1)** and **2)** but there's a brick wall at **step 3)**

[image]

The problem is that simply using `bitmapdata.draw(video_container);` does not work but instead it throws a Policy File error even though I am using a `byteArray` (from local video file in the same directory as the SWF). No internet is even involved but Flash tells me that `"No Policy File granted permission from the server"` or such nonsense. I think the error is just a bail-out insteading of straight up saying "You are not allowed to do this.."

**I have tried:** trying to appease this `Crossdomain.xml` issue anyway and looking into all known security/domain settings. I came to the conclusion that the error is not the problem but a side effect of the issue.. The issue here being that: `Flash Player` is aware of the SWF's location and of any files local to it. That's okay when you pass a `String` as URL etc but when the `Netstream` data is not local to the SWF domain then it becomes a Policy File issue. Problem is my data is in the Memory not in a folder like the SWF and therefore cannot alllow `bitmapData.draw` since it cannot "police" an array of bytes, **any known fixes for this?**... (I can't even say the words I really wanted to use).

**What I am trying to achieve:** Is to essentially use Netstream as an H.263 or H.264 image decoder in the same way `Loader` is a JPEG-to-Bitmap decoder or `LoadCompressed..` is an MP3-to-PCM decoder. You know, access the raw material (here RGB pixels), apply some effects functions and then send to screen or save to disk.

Comment: Do you want to extract an image from a video stream as snapshot ? or doing that using `NetStream.appendBytes` which do the inverse ( inject data into a `NetStream` object ) ?

Comment: Hi, I want to extract **from** not put **into**, making a video frame from existing bitmapdata is the easy part (ie: no hassle). It's when I bring in an FLV/MP4 file and append a frame then suddenly I'm not allowed to snapshot those decoded bytes to some `bitmapData`. It's really strange...

Comment: Hi, +1 for the good effort but it's not the correct answer. To quote your answer **"To take a snapshot... we don't need NetStream.appendBytes which inject data into a NetStream object"** well that's the **problem** and whole point of the question.. I'm injecting bytes to be decoded so I can take a snapshot of the output image. There is no URL to put in a `String` but instead I have a `Byte Array` (which is why the security error makes no sense, how can anyone "Policy File" a bytearray??). Anyway I think I found a possible solution just need time to double check it..

Comment: Hi, sorry man if I have not understood your question. I think what your are looking for is not dowable now because simply it's an Adobe bug. Take a look [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5277700), the bug is [here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3617751) and a bug workaround [here](http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/2014/11/netstream-playnull-bitmapdata-workaround/) and [here](http://summitprojectsflashblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/bitmapdata-draw-does-not-get-along-with-netconnection-connectnull/).

Comment: I think I found a solution for your problem, take a look to my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a little late, but I think I found a solution for your problem.

So, to avoid the **Security sandbox violation #2123 Error**, you have just to do like this :

```
// ...

net_stream.play(null);

net_stream.play('');

// ...
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks!! This works great and it also avoids security error for computespectrum too (when using appendBytes). Genius. VC

Answer (score 1):

To take a snapshot from a video stream we don't need `NetStream.appendBytes` which inject data into a `NetStream` object.

For that we can use [`BitmapData.draw`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) which has some security constraints. That's why in many times we get a flash security error. About that, Adobe said :

> "*... This method is supported over RTMP in Flash Player 9.0.115.0 and later and in Adobe AIR. You can control access to streams on Flash Media Server in a server-side script. For more information, see the Client.audioSampleAccess and Client.videoSampleAccess properties in Server-Side ActionScript Language Reference for Adobe Flash Media Server. If the source object and (in the case of a Sprite or MovieClip object) all of its child objects do not come from the same domain as the caller, or are not in a content that is accessible to the caller by having called the Security.allowDomain() method, a call to the draw() throws a SecurityError exception. This restriction does not apply to AIR content in the application security sandbox. ...*".

For crossdomain file creation and some other security config for AMS server, you can take a look on this post : [Crossdomain Video Snapshot - Fixing BitmapData.draw() Security Sandbox Violation](http://www.thebluepipe.com/Developer/tutorials/as3/Crossdomain-Video-Snapshot-Fixing-BitmapData-draw-Security-Sandbox-Violation.html).

After allowing our script to get data from our video stream, we can pass to the code.

I wrote a code that play a video stream ( rtmp or http ) and take a snapshot to show it in the stage or save it as a file after applying a [pixel effect](http://www.yannkozon.com/blog/397-pixel-art-webcam/) :

```
const server:String = null; //'rtmp://localhost/vod'
const stream:String = 'stream'; // 'mp4:big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mp4';
var nc:NetConnection;
var ns:NetStream;
var video:Video;
const jpg_quality:int = 80;
const px_size:int = 10;

nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, function(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void{});
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function(e:NetStatusEvent):void{
    if(e.info.code == 'NetConnection.Connect.Success'){
        ns = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function(e:NetStatusEvent):void{});
        ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, function(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void{});
        video = new Video(320, 180);
        video.x = video.y = 10;
        video.attachNetStream(ns);
        addChild(video);
        ns.play(stream);
    }
})
nc.connect(server);

btn_show.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent): void{
        var bmp:Bitmap = pixelate(video, px_size);
            bmp.x = 10;
            bmp.y = 220;
        addChild(bmp);
    }
)
btn_save.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent): void{

        var bmp:Bitmap = pixelate(video, px_size);

        var jpg_encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
        var jpg_stream:ByteArray = jpg_encoder.encode(bmp.bitmapData);

        var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
            file.save(jpg_stream, 'snapshot_'+int(ns.time)+'.jpg');

    }
)

function pixelate(target:DisplayObject, px_size:uint):Bitmap {

    var i:uint, j:uint = 0;
    var s:uint = px_size;
    var d:DisplayObject = target;

    var w:uint = d.width;
    var h:uint = d.height;

    var bmd_src:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
        bmd_src.draw(d);

    var bmd_final:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);

    var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rec.width = rec.height = s;

    for (i = 0; i < w; i += s){
        for (j = 0; j < h; j += s){
            rec.x = i;
            rec.y = j;                  
            bmd_final.fillRect(rec, bmd_src.getPixel32(i, j));
        }
    }

    bmd_src.dispose();
    bmd_src = null;

    return new Bitmap(bmd_final);
}
```

Of course, this is just a simple example to show the manner to get a snapshot from a video stream, you should adapt and improve it to your needs ...

I hope all that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a couple months old, but I wanted to post the correct answer (because I just had this problem as well and other will too).

Correct answer:

It's a bug that has been open at adobe for almost 2 years

[Link to the bug on Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3617751)

Work Around until the bug gets fixed (I am using this and it works great):

[Workaround using Sprite and graphics](http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/2014/11/netstream-playnull-bitmapdata-workaround)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That workaround link was indeed helpful. I had already found it (as mentioned [in the last sentence here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464444/getting-bitmap-after-netstream-appendbytes-as3/29283532#comment43394082_27464444) ). My problem then was it came with extra issues for what I was particularly doing (h264 bytes, aligning source vid with drawn vid, problems with drawing black if metadata-less files whilst showing a "drawable" picture etc. **Thinking to provide an answer with working example + code, I'll still hook you up with "correct answer" rep though**

Comment: I think I found a solution for your problem, take a look to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33427890/2256820).